# Saving multiple GoogleService-Info.plists with the same name on the same computer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

So I've recently started learning how to implement Firebase to my Xcode projects, and as I understand, every project needs to have this file to connect with Firebase, and it has to be named exactly like "GoogleService-Info.plist". However, I'm at a lost because I created a new iOS app that also needs its own GoogleService-Info.plist but I can't save the file with that name without replacing the old one for a different project, and if I changed the name of the plist, it won't configure properly. How should I go about this?

I tried finding ways to let Firebase configure the app using the custom name for the GoogleServices plist file, but every time I ran the app it gives "Thread 1: "`FirebaseApp.configure()` could not find a valid GoogleService-Info.plist in your project. Please download one from [https://console.firebase.google.com/."](https://console.firebase.google.com/.%22)

The code I tried to use was from the Google's Firebase doc, with a plist file named "CustomGoogleService-Ifo.plist"

```
let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "CustomGoogleService-Info", ofType: "plist")
        guard let fileopts = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: filePath!)
          else { assert(false, "Couldn't load config file") }
        FirebaseApp.configure(options: fileopts)
         
        FirebaseApp.configure()
```

Comment: I don't understand why there are two calls to FirebaseApp.configure.  Is the second one a copy-paste error?  If you remove that, does it work?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Are you saying you have a brand new project that needs to connect to two totally separate Firebase database projects? If not, what's the user case for needing two `GoogleService-Info.plist`?

Answer (score 1):

Each project gets its own GoogleService-Info.plist. After downloading it, you don't have to keep it within the Download folder or one specific folder, you can move it to the specific project folder.

Project A folder contains the GoogleService-Info.plist for project A and the Project B folder contains the GoogleService-Info.plist for project B.
Since you use different folders, of course you can use the same name.

Add the GoogleService-Info.plist via "Add Files to..." and make sure that the file has the right Target Memberships.

Please see my screenshots:

[image: Project A, you can see GoogleService-Info.plist]

[image: Project B, you also can see different GoogleService-Info.plist]

Comment: Quick question for clarity; it appears your screen shots show two separate projects, TwentyFour and SportsClub each with their own plist - which is fine. The question seems to indicate the OP wants one project with two plists. Perhaps I am not looking at the answer correctly?

Comment: Hi @Jay, due to the part `I created a new iOS app that also needs its own GoogleService-Info.plist, but I can't save the file with that name without replacing the old one for a different project` in the description, I think he is talking about 2 individual apps / 2 individual projects. @the-mega-gudetama, can you please confirm or clarify?